# trying to call user_id from sqlite

Tags: java, android-sqlite

I'm trying to call user_id from sqlite database but I get this error

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0 SQLITE_OK): Queries can be performed using SQLiteDatabase query or rawQuery methods only.
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)

```
public Database user_id(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = String.format("SELECT user_id FROM OrderDetails ;");
    db.execSQL(query);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {

        c.moveToFirst();
    }
        return user_id();
}
```

Please don't recommend another solution because I'm stuck with this for more than a day and I tried almost all solutions represented in stackoverflow and online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String)

> public void execSQL (String sql)
>  Execute a single SQL statement
>   that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns
>   data.

So remove this line:

```
db.execSQL(query);
```

The method `execSQL()` is not used to execute queries that fetch rows, like SELECT statements. You can use it with INSERT, UPDATE, CREATE, etc.
Also, I think that you want to return the user's ids as a `Cursor`, right? 
So why:

```
public Database user_id()
```

this returns a Database object (whatever this is).
Change the method to this:

```
public Cursor user_id(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT user_id FROM OrderDetails";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return c;
}
```